# Stackdriver monitoring - Metric Absent

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to monitor and get alert when my instance shut down. For this I have configured Alert policy in stackdriver as below:

Metric Absence Condition

Violates when: CPU Usage (GCE Monitoring) is absent for greater than 5 minutes

It worked only for first time and then never created any incident for any of stopped instances. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: What notification channels did you configure the alert policy with? If you using the email channels, e-mails are usually sent from alerts@stackdriver.com, so make sure that the address is not being filtered or blocked by your email client. You may also try with another channel.

Comment: I have configured email for alert notification but I think the problem is from monitoring metric itself because there is no incident shown on stackdriver monitoring GUI even.

Comment: You have a valid point, if the policy conditions are met and yet no entries are made under Alerting/Incidents then this is not likely an issue with the channels. You'd mentioned earlier that it worked right after setup, was there any entry logged for that violation? Also while in advanced filter in Stackdriver Logging, using the following filter to check if there're logs for that VM 

`resource.type="gce_instance" AND (resource.labels.instance_id="[VM instance ID]" AND resource.labels.zone="[Zone]" AND resource.labels.project_id="[Project Name]")`

Comment: To find the VM instance ID, go on the VM instance page, click on the VM you are monitoring -> scroll down and click Equivalent REST, and check the REST response code for something like this:  `"id": "87117864331903404213",`. If no logs are found this way, I will recommend submitting a [private issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901) in Google issue tracker. This will create a private issue that only you and Googlers will have access to with the affected project number. So the support team can further investigate this issue.

Comment: Thanks @SunnyJ. , I will try this and come back.

Answer (score 1):

**Expected Behavior**

@Jyotsna. I investigated this issue a bit more and was able to confirm that this is currently an expected behavior, as alert conditions aren't triggered by inactive instances which explains why, you won't get any alerts when the VM instance CPU is not registering any metrics. However, there's currently a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119491735) in progress to update this behavior.

**Known Issue**

There's also a known issue which seems to have caused the behavior of no logs being sent to Stackdriver on subsequent violations of the policy even after the offending VM is back online. This explains why,

> It worked only for first time and then never created any incident for any of stopped instances.

Hence stopped instances won't work properly until the issue is fixed. Unfortunately, there's no ETA. on this, but eventually, it will be addressed.

Comment: Thanks @Sunny, I raised a support request to Google and they explained the same. I find it ambiguous, since there is alert sent first time. According to Metrics absent documentation by Google, there should a data point to monitor, hence, when first time instance goes down the stackdriver agent logs incident and sends alert. Now when the instance is up again and running, it is no more inactive, the agent should be running again and monitoring again and should behave exactly same as before, assuming there will be usage metrics logged again. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119491735 was created by there support team on my request. :)

Comment: @Jyotsna. You are not wrong, this is absolutely correct. I further investigated this issue, and it seems this is currently a known issue in Metric absence alerts. Hence stopped instances won't work properly until the issue is fixed. Unfortunately, there's no ETA. on this, but a fix is currently been worked on.  I also updated the above answer to reflect this.

Comment: The issue is still open. IMO this is a basic feature of any monitoring system which depends on metrics - but Stackdriver does not have it yet. Prometheus supports this easily with its QL.